# Terraform GCP Unsupported escape sequence in regex

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, escaping, terraform

I am trying to set up custom metrics in GCP using terraform code.
I have a problem with the label extractor part to get 4xx and 5xx response codes. 
Basing on console response and Google builder I managed to create this regex:

```
\\s([4-5][0-9][0-9])\\s\
```

- When I run code with this regex I get this response:

> googleapi: Error 400: Failed to parse extractor expression:
>   unsupported escape sequence in a string literal at line 1, column 36,
>   token '"\s([1-5][0-9][0-9])\s"'

- When I send regex without white spaces (`\\s`) code works flawlessly.
- I have tried different variations of `\` before `"\` parts, but none seemed to work.

```
extracted_label = "REGEXP_EXTRACT(jsonPayload.message, \"\\s([1-5][0-9][0-9])\\s\")"
```

I would like to be able to create a metric, but I cannot bypass the unsupported escape sequence problem. 
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to find answer by myself to this question.
The correct way is using 4 slashes `\\\\`
Fixed code line should look like this:

```
extracted_label = "REGEXP_EXTRACT(jsonPayload.message, \"\\\\s([4-5][0-9][0-9])\\\\s\")"
```

Also, if someone would look for sample code in Terraform GCP to pull HTTP response code from readiness health check here is one:

```
extracted_label = "REGEXP_EXTRACT(jsonPayload.message, \"\\\\w+\\\\/\\\\d\\\\.\\\\d\\\"\\\\s([4-5][0-9][0-9])\")"
```